# Mostrar mensaje si un dato no está presente en la base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Quisiera saber si existe una forma de mostrar un mensaje dentro de la consulta si un dato no existe en la base de datos.
He probado con case y null pero no funciona ya que no hay un registro dentro de la base de datos.
Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT CASE WHERE id IS NULL 
THEN "No está en db" END FROM 
users WHERE user_id=123
```

Aquí no hay ningún registro con ese id, entonces me gustaría mostrar que no existe ese dato.

Comment: No es muy ortodoxo manejar ese tipo de mensaje en SQL.

Comment: @Sal eso no quiere decir que no se pueda hacer, miralo como un reto, SQL es un lenguaje potente que permite hacer casi todo

Comment: Hola shelkanife, podrías decirme si la respuesta dada te resultó útil y en caso de haberlo sido podrías marcarla como aceptada y si lo deseas también darle un voto positivo, gracias

Comment: @Japv *"Para un martillo, todos son clavos"*; lejos de ser un reto, es un anti-patrón (*silver bullet*, *golden hammer*).

Comment: @Sal dime que tiene de malo que el usuario quiera probar una consulta que arroje este resultado, ya sea por reto, o por una tarea escolar, o simplemente probar cosas para darse cuenta de otras, de verdad que no entiendo xq la cogen con la respuesta, si es un antipatron yo mismo le puedo aclarar desde mi respuesta que no es una buena practica, pero igual le respondo lo que pide

Comment: @Sal hice una nueva respuesta donde le respondo su inquietud y a la vez le aclaro que no es una buena práctica, espero de esta forma quedar bien con todas las partes, incluyendome a mi, gracias por todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de varios debates muy constructivos con otros miembros de la comunidad te aclaro que lo que pides **no es una buena práctica**, solo tú sabrás lo que pretendes, no obstante te respondo a tu inquietud, pero te repito que lo que deseas hacer **no es una buena práctica**.

```
select 
 case
  when T.Total = 0 then "No existe"
 end as Mensaje
from
(
 select count(*) as Total
 from users 
 where user_id = 123
) T
```

Se hace una **consulta interna** que va a contar el total de registros dado un criterio y sobre esta consulta se aplica otra consulta más general donde si se utiliza el **case when** para mostrar el mensaje que pides atendiendo a si el **campo Total** es **0**..

Comment: Por favor, no agregues más respuestas, realiza solo una respuesta, recuerda que puedes editarla para mejorarla, revisar [answer], saludos.